# how to send mail asynchronously in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to send email to multiple recipients using php codeigniter. The probelm is it is taking lot of time to send mails. I have save email id in the database to later send the emails from the background.

```
$baseUrl = BASE_URL;
$sendmailurl = $baseUrl."index.php/SendEmail";
exec("wget -qO- $sendmailurl  &> /dev/null &");
```

sendEmail is my controller that read data from database and sends mail. But exec is not executing in the background, browser waits until all the email has been sent to all the addresses in the database.

Comment: you could to regsiter emails in database and perform a script via cronjob later

Comment: agree with above @felipsmartins and or a queue could be utilized.

Comment: On Unix systems, PHP's mail command only works with a local mailer. Unless your MTA installation is deliberately broken it will manage a mail queue and forward messages asynchronously. You told us nothing about the platform this runs on but instead have hinted at an infrastructure which is a silly way to solve the problem.

Comment: STRONGLY DISAGREE WITH felipsmartins. CREATING YOUR OWN MTA IS A VERY BAD SOLUTION

Comment: @symcbean good point, I really overlook the headaches that can come later with creating your own.

Comment: exec("(wget php $sendmailurl) > /dev/null 2>&1 &",$out,$ret); this code works for me..

Comment: Oh dear. From bad to worse.

Answer (score 0):

You could fire the event to send the email or post to a webhook to take care of it somewhere to decouple this emailing .

For example if you have a dedicated place to send email then you could do this.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 
Host: emailer.example.org 
Content-Type: application/json
 {"email_address":"destination@server.com","subject":"Foobar", "body":"Email body"}
```

In this way you decouple email service with whatever you are doing. Or you can use Message Queues like Rabbit MQ to fire email event async

Answer (score 0):

It really does not look like your command is formatted just right.  This is taken from the [PHP manual page for exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329) in the comments and seems to be platform agnostic.

```
<?php 
    function execInBackground($cmd) { 
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
        } 
        else { 
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
        } 
    } 
?>
```